# C Windows API keyboard

Tags: c, windows, api, keyboard

I made a program that types a string to the computer. Everything works fine but I got two problems: 1. When I put a capital letter it doesn't write the capital letter. 2. When I write two of the same letters next to each other, one of them doesn't get written. I read a lot of the Windows API documentation but couldn't find anything. Can someone help me solving the problems?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

void keyboard(char *str)
{
    int x = strlen(str);

    INPUT inputStruct[x];
    ZeroMemory(inputStruct, sizeof(inputStruct));

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        inputStruct[i].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inputStruct[i].ki.wVk = VkKeyScanA(str[i]);
    }

    SendInput(x, inputStruct, sizeof(INPUT));
}

int main()
{
    keyboard("hoe is het");
}
```

Comment: Does this code even compile? You have an array of non-const size!

Comment: I calculate the size of the array at the first line of the function?

Comment: Yes but in a normal program you can't use strlen to set the size of a stack allocated array. You might get lucky here and the compiler calculates it at compile time. Change `strlen` to `lstrlenA` and see what happens.

Comment: It still works?

Comment: C99 might allow that or as a GCC extension but I suppose it is not relevant since you can't know the correct size based on the string alone when using virtual keys.

Comment: So I have to pass the size of the string because it is safer?

Comment: The number of INPUTs might be 6 times (maybe 8 if Shift+AltGr is a thing) as many as the string length.

Answer (score 0):

- `VkKeyScan` returns 16-bits of information, the upper 8 is information about which modifier keys need to be pressed, in your case most likely "shift".
- Each character needs at minimum 2 INPUT events, the last of each with `KEYEVENTF_KEYUP` set to release the key.
- You can simulate text input with the `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE` flag so you don't have to deal with keyboard shift states.

Just using the Unicode flag is easy. Manually setting the keyboard state is error prone, this makes a halfhearted attempt:

```
void SendTextInputASCII(LPCTSTR str)
{
    SIZE_T i;
    INPUT ki[2];
    ZeroMemory(&ki, sizeof(ki));
    for (i = 0; str[i]; ++i)
    {
        ki[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        ki[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
        ki[0].ki.wScan = str[i]; // TODO: To properly support non-ASCII you need to fill this with the correct Unicode codepoint.
        ki[1] = ki[0];
        ki[1].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        SendInput(2, ki, sizeof(INPUT));
    }
}

void SendCharacterInput(TCHAR ch)
{
    UINT info = VkKeyScan(ch), wantshift, hadshift;
    INPUT ki[2];
    ZeroMemory(&ki, sizeof(ki));
    hadshift = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT) < 0;
    wantshift = HIBYTE(info) & 1;
    if (wantshift != hadshift)
    {
        ki[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        ki[0].ki.dwFlags = hadshift ? KEYEVENTF_KEYUP : 0;
        ki[0].ki.wVk = VK_LSHIFT;
        SendInput(1, ki, sizeof(INPUT));
    }
    // TODO: Should also handle Control and Alt keys!
    ki[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ki[0].ki.dwFlags = 0;
    ki[0].ki.wVk = LOBYTE(info);
    ki[1] = ki[0];
    ki[1].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(2, ki, sizeof(INPUT));
    if (wantshift != hadshift)
    {
        ki[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        ki[0].ki.dwFlags = wantshift ? KEYEVENTF_KEYUP : 0;
        ki[0].ki.wVk = VK_LSHIFT;
        SendInput(1, ki, sizeof(INPUT));
    }
}

void SendCharactersInput(LPCTSTR str)
{
    SIZE_T i;
    for (i = 0; str[i]; ++i)
        SendCharacterInput(str[i]);
}

void Example()
{
    LPCTSTR text = TEXT("Hello World\n");
    WinExec("Notepad.exe", SW_SHOW);
    Sleep(2000);

    SendTextInputASCII(text);
    SendCharactersInput(text);
}
```

Comment: I still can't get it worked. I checked: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-vkkeyscana but I don't read anywhere that I can press the shift button

Comment: I edited my code to this

Comment: I have to do something inside the if statement to write a capital letter

Comment: If you insist on using VkKeyScan then you have to check the upper bits of its return value and SendInput for Shift/Control/Alt if required. Just using KEYEVENTF_UNICODE is easier

Comment: How do I check the bits?

Comment: I'm banging my head against the wall

Comment: Then you need to learn about bits and bytes. `WORD x = VkKeyScan(..), shift = HIBYTE(x) & 1;`

Comment: Can you give a example code of how I can type the capital letters also?